# Can I abbreviate df[ !is.na(df$val) & df$val > 15]?

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison, na

I have a dataframe from which I want to extract the records where the value in `val` is greater than 15 and those whose `val` is not `NA`:

```
 df[ !is.na(df$val) & df$val > 15, ]
```

Since I assume that such a comparison is often needed in R, I am wondering if this comparison can be abbreviated somewow. In fact, I'd not be surprised if this question is already asked on StackOverflow - but I was unable to come up with a search that found it.

Comment: Data table way: `library(data.table);   setDT(df);   df[!is.na(val) & val>15]`

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(df); df[val>15]` Because you are requiring val>15, all NAs will disappear because it will NA>15 is NA

Comment: @d.b I forgot the `, ` in the brackets - it's now added.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use it, but it I can save a few keystrokes, I am more than happy to learn it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subset` omits NA values and also avoids repeating `df`:

```
subset(df, val > 15)
```

`which` also eliminates NA values but `df` must be repeated:

```
df[which(df$val > 15), ]
```

The dplyr package's `filter` is like base `subset`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(val > 15)
```

Using `sqldf` the NA values are dropped.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * from df where val > 15")
```